# Xamarin Forms Cross and Camera control

Tags: xamarin, camera, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

For my studying project, I need to realize an application that has a CameraView or a CameraPage, with a special design. However, I’m not able to figure out how to realize it.

I found a lot of information, to be honest, but they are either obsolete or incomplete, so, I would like to make a point about it, through this thread!

---

### How to implement a Camera?

Well, two solutions can be considered based on what I read.

**Camera Page**

Let’s say that it’s the first “official” solution. It’s proposed by Xamarin itself, with the **[Customizing a ContentPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage/)** tutorial/documentation. It explains you, through a web page how to implement the camera service with a cross-platform solution.

I then tried the UWP solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CameraPreviewProject.Sources.Pages.CameraPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Button Text="Click me !" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Finally, the C# side gives us this:

```
public partial class CameraPage : ContentPage
{
    public CameraPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then, we create a renderer in the UWP side :

```
using CameraPreviewProject.Sources.Pages;
using CameraPreviewProject.UWP.Sources.PageRenderers;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Sensors;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Media;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.FileProperties;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.System.Display;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraPage), typeof(CameraPageRenderer))]

namespace CameraPreviewProject.UWP.Sources.PageRenderers
{
    public class CameraPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private readonly DisplayInformation displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        private readonly SimpleOrientationSensor orientationSensor = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();
        private readonly DisplayRequest displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
        private SimpleOrientation deviceOrientation = SimpleOrientation.NotRotated;
        private DisplayOrientations displayOrientation = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;

        // Rotation metadata to apply to preview stream (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868174.aspx)
        private static readonly Guid RotationKey = new Guid("C380465D-2271-428C-9B83-ECEA3B4A85C1"); // (MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION)

        private StorageFolder captureFolder = null;

        private readonly SystemMediaTransportControls systemMediaControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();

        private MediaCapture mediaCapture;
        private CaptureElement captureElement;
        private bool isInitialized;
        private bool isPreviewing;
        private bool externalCamera;
        private bool mirroringPreview;

        private Page page;
        private AppBarButton takePhotoButton;
        private Application app;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                app = Application.Current;
                app.Suspending += OnAppSuspending;
                app.Resuming += OnAppResuming;

                SetupUserInterface();
                SetupCamera();

                this.Children.Add(page);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"      ERROR: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            page.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height));
            return finalSize;
        }

        private void SetupUserInterface()
        {
            takePhotoButton = new AppBarButton
            {
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Camera)
            };

            var commandBar = new CommandBar();
            commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(takePhotoButton);

            captureElement = new CaptureElement();
            captureElement.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;

            var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
            stackPanel.Children.Add(captureElement);

            page = new Page();
            page.BottomAppBar = commandBar;
            page.Content = stackPanel;
            page.Unloaded += OnPageUnloaded;
        }

        private async void SetupCamera()
        {
            await SetupUIAsync();
            await InitializeCameraAsync();
        }

        #region Event Handlers

        private async void OnSystemMediaControlsPropertyChanged(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                // Only handle event if the page is being displayed
                if (args.Property == SystemMediaTransportControlsProperty.SoundLevel && page.Frame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(MainPage))
                {
                    // Check if the app is being muted. If so, it's being minimized
                    // Otherwise if it is not initialized, it's being brought into focus
                    if (sender.SoundLevel == SoundLevel.Muted)
                    {
                        await CleanupCameraAsync();
                    }
                    else if (!isInitialized)
                    {
                        await InitializeCameraAsync();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void OnOrientationSensorOrientationChanged(SimpleOrientationSensor sender, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Only update orientatino if the device is not parallel to the ground
            if (args.Orientation != SimpleOrientation.Faceup && args.Orientation != SimpleOrientation.Facedown)
            {
                deviceOrientation = args.Orientation;
            }
        }

        private async void OnDisplayInformationOrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
        {
            displayOrientation = sender.CurrentOrientation;

            if (isPreviewing)
            {
                await SetPreviewRotationAsync();
            }
        }

        private async void OnTakePhotoButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await TakePhotoAsync();
        }

        /*async void OnHardwareCameraButtonPressed(object sender, CameraEventArgs e)
        {
            await TakePhotoAsync();
        }*/

        #endregion Event Handlers

        #region Media Capture

        private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
        {
            if (mediaCapture == null)
            {
                var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
                var cameraDevice = devices.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EnclosureLocation != null && c.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
                // Get any camera if there isn't one on the back panel
                cameraDevice = cameraDevice ?? devices.FirstOrDefault();

                if (cameraDevice == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No camera found");
                    return;
                }

                mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                try
                {
                    await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
                    {
                        VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id,
                        AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
                        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                        PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo
                    });
                    isInitialized = true;
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Camera access denied");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception initializing MediaCapture - {0}: {1}", cameraDevice.Id, ex.ToString());
                }

                if (isInitialized)
                {
                    if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null || cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown)
                    {
                        externalCamera = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Camera is on device
                        externalCamera = false;

                        // Mirror preview if camera is on front panel
                        mirroringPreview = (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
                    }
                    await StartPreviewAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
        {
            // Prevent the device from sleeping while the preview is running
            displayRequest.RequestActive();

            // Setup preview source in UI and mirror if required
            captureElement.Source = mediaCapture;
            captureElement.FlowDirection = mirroringPreview ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

            // Start preview
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            isPreviewing = true;

            if (isPreviewing)
            {
                await SetPreviewRotationAsync();
            }
        }

        private async Task StopPreviewAsync()
        {
            isPreviewing = false;
            await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();

            // Use dispatcher because sometimes this method is called from non-UI threads
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                // UI cleanup
                captureElement.Source = null;

                // Allow device screen to sleep now preview is stopped
                displayRequest.RequestRelease();
            });
        }

        private async Task SetPreviewRotationAsync()
        {
            // Only update the orientation if the camera is mounted on the device
            if (externalCamera)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Derive the preview rotation
            int rotation = ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(displayOrientation);

            // Invert if mirroring
            if (mirroringPreview)
            {
                rotation = (360 - rotation) % 360;
            }

            // Add rotation metadata to preview stream
            var props = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
            props.Properties.Add(RotationKey, rotation);
            await mediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, props, null);
        }

        private async Task TakePhotoAsync()
        {
            var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);

            try
            {
                var file = await captureFolder.CreateFileAsync("photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                var orientation = ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(GetCameraOrientation());
                await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, file, orientation);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception when taking photo: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private async Task CleanupCameraAsync()
        {
            if (isInitialized)
            {
                if (isPreviewing)
                {
                    await StopPreviewAsync();
                }
                isInitialized = false;
            }
            if (mediaCapture != null)
            {
                mediaCapture.Dispose();
                mediaCapture = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion Media Capture

        #region Helpers

        private async Task SetupUIAsync()
        {
            // Lock page to landscape to prevent the capture element from rotating
            DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;

            /*// Hide status bar
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
            {
                await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
            }*/

            displayOrientation = displayInformation.CurrentOrientation;
            if (orientationSensor != null)
            {
                deviceOrientation = orientationSensor.GetCurrentOrientation();
            }

            RegisterEventHandlers();

            var picturesLibrary = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
            // Fallback to local app storage if no pictures library
            captureFolder = picturesLibrary.SaveFolder ?? ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        }

        private async Task CleanupUIAsync()
        {
            UnregisterEventHandlers();

            /*if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
            {
                await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ShowAsync();
            }*/

            // Revert orientation preferences
            DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.None;
        }

        private void RegisterEventHandlers()
        {
            /*if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                HardwareButtons.CameraPressed += OnHardwareCameraButtonPressed;
            }*/

            if (orientationSensor != null)
            {
                orientationSensor.OrientationChanged += OnOrientationSensorOrientationChanged;
            }

            displayInformation.OrientationChanged += OnDisplayInformationOrientationChanged;
            systemMediaControls.PropertyChanged += OnSystemMediaControlsPropertyChanged;
            takePhotoButton.Click += OnTakePhotoButtonClicked;
        }

        private void UnregisterEventHandlers()
        {
            /*if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                HardwareButtons.CameraPressed -= OnHardwareCameraButtonPressed;
            }*/

            if (orientationSensor != null)
            {
                orientationSensor.OrientationChanged -= OnOrientationSensorOrientationChanged;
            }

            displayInformation.OrientationChanged -= OnDisplayInformationOrientationChanged;
            systemMediaControls.PropertyChanged -= OnSystemMediaControlsPropertyChanged;
            takePhotoButton.Click -= OnTakePhotoButtonClicked;
        }

        private static async Task ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, StorageFile file, PhotoOrientation orientation)
        {
            using (var inputStream = stream)
            {
                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

                using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(outputStream, decoder);
                    var properties = new BitmapPropertySet
                    {
                        {
                            "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(orientation, Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.UInt16)
                        }
                    };

                    await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Helpers

        #region Rotation

        private SimpleOrientation GetCameraOrientation()
        {
            if (externalCamera)
            {
                // Cameras that aren't attached to the device do not rotate along with it
                return SimpleOrientation.NotRotated;
            }

            var result = deviceOrientation;

            // On portrait-first devices, the camera sensor is mounted at a 90 degree offset to the native orientation
            if (displayInformation.NativeOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait)
            {
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.NotRotated;
                        break;

                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise;
                        break;

                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise;
                        break;

                    case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise;
                        break;
                }
            }

            // If the preview is mirrored for a front-facing camera, invert the rotation
            if (mirroringPreview)
            {
                // Rotating 0 and 180 ddegrees is the same clockwise and anti-clockwise
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        return SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise;

                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        return SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static int ConvertDeviceOrientationToDegrees(SimpleOrientation orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return 90;

                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return 180;

                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return 270;

                case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        private static int ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(DisplayOrientations orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case DisplayOrientations.Portrait:
                    return 90;

                case DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped:
                    return 180;

                case DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped:
                    return 270;

                case DisplayOrientations.Landscape:
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        private static PhotoOrientation ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(SimpleOrientation orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Rotate90;

                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Rotate180;

                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Rotate270;

                case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                default:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Normal;
            }
        }

        #endregion Rotation

        #region Lifecycle

        private async void OnAppSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            await CleanupCameraAsync();
            await CleanupUIAsync();
            deferral.Complete();
        }

        private async void OnAppResuming(object sender, object o)
        {
            await SetupUIAsync();
            await InitializeCameraAsync();
        }

        private async void OnPageUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await CleanupCameraAsync();
            await CleanupUIAsync();
        }

        #endregion Lifecycle
    }
}
```

This idea is pretty logic, you have a basic page, but which have renderer that preview the camera in the background, I mean, this is the idea I understood, however, it only gives you a white screen that throws an exception… (x86)

```
Exception initializing MediaCapture - \\?\USB#VID_045E&PID_0779&MI_00#6&2E9BBB25&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\GLOBAL: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00DABE6): The current capture source does not have an independent photo stream.
The current capture source does not have an independent photo stream.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at CameraPreviewProject.UWP.Sources.PageRenderers.CameraPageRenderer.<InitializeCameraAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
```

Then I click the button of the downside woft menu and get:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
WinRT information: This object needs to be initialized before the requested operation can be carried out.
```

I’m a Xamarin Fan, but on that part, I’m not. [This link about MediaCapture can be interesting though!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture)

**CameraView**

*To be honest, it’s so way easier to have a control as a button!*

```
<Camera/>
```

Well, let’s have a look at it! I found  a couple of solutions:

- [Moment](https://blog.xamarin.com/build-your-own-snapchat-clone-with-xamarin.forms-and-azure/) *MVVM logic - It seems to work only with Android & iOS*
- [Xlabs Camera](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera) *Unable to try since I can’t start VS2017 from the .sln. Also, I couldn't test the UWP side because it's an MVVM logic..*
- [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) *This solution works on UWP !! But run a new activity/instance/page with a native design, so this isn't the solution searched*

So, my question is “Does someone could create an element `public class Camera()` that can be used and declared as a simple xamarin forms button?”

Because, I saw as well 2 others projects about it, one I can’t remember, but the second one is [Barcode Scanning](https://blog.xamarin.com/barcode-scanning-made-easy-with-zxing-net-for-xamarin-forms/) but I’m not able to understand or take back the code to implement it as I would like…

It seems so easy and it’s so hard to get, why? Because finally, we’re talking about a view/image that displays a stream from a camera? A camera is just a service where you have methods such as `TakePictureAsync()` or anything like that? `Rotate()`, `Switch(ViewSide vs)`, etc etc?

So, I searched about getting a frame view or display the stream of the camera into an image or a view.. I began from those links:

- [UWP get live webcam video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945265/uwp-get-live-webcam-video-stream) by **David Pine**
- [UWP stream Webcam over socket to mediaElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812506/uwp-streaming-webcam-over-socket-to-mediaelement-broken-picture) *I just made some changes
  because the subject is a bit different, but.. I couldn't make it work*

To be honest, I don’t know what to try now… I’m lost because, at the same time, I tried some Xamarin Forms solution, but also some proper UWP solutions and … nothing…. Maybe my point of view is not good, maybe my idea and just on the side, maybe I should try another approach, I don’t know at all..

I was also thinking about creating a class with some interface that I redefine in each platform renderer, but, still nothing…

Do you have please, any idea or any approach?

---

Note I have cross-posed this to the [Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/284359/#Comment_284359).

Comment: show what you gave tried (at least one solution) and what is the problem in hat case?

Comment: I have used this in the past and have found it to work for taking pictures and videos easily enough https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: I got on message on Xamarin Forums and, I think I'll just make a big post about the multiple solutions I tried, but also how to implement them and where they don't work, or the problem they don't solve

Comment: @YuriS Updated !

Comment: You are trying UWP. Unfortunately I don't have computer with Windows and camera, so I cannot try any code for UWP. Do you have problems on another platforms or just UWP?

Comment: Well, with android, I can't compile at the moment, but it's temporary I guess, some update of some packages

Comment: Hello, for media plugin, there have default camera which is 
DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front

If i want make the flash light was always on, so any default function can be set like the default camera?

Comment: @Emixam23 My dude, I'm so sorry you have to go through all this... I'm currently stuck on getting camera working and I'm using the Media plugin thing from JamesMontagno (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) working cross platform, but on UWP it starts up the "Camera" app which is slow as heck and now I'm trying to use the custom render example (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/) to get the camera as a stream embedded in a page

I'm searching around for a way to use that stream from the custom render to actually show the image to the user